# NextJS Build error: package.json does not exist at /package.json

Tags: next.js

I have been working on a NextJS application that utilizes Firebase. I have everything set up and on build I get the following error: `package.json does not exist at /package.json` (see the image)

[build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CxxW.png)

To give more context on this:

- NextJS v^9.3.0
- Firebase v^7.10.0
- Target: server (by default)

My next.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path')
const resolve = require('resolve')
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withImages = require('next-images')
const withFonts = require('next-fonts')
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '*************',
  '*************',
  '*************'
]);

if (typeof require !== "undefined") {
 require.extensions[".less"] = () => {};
 require.extensions[".css"] = (file) => {};
}

module.exports = 
  withCSS(
    withImages(
      withFonts(
        withTM({
          webpack: (config, options) => {
            config.module.rules.push({
              test: /\.svg$/,
              use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
            });
            const { dir, isServer } = options
            config.externals = []
            if (isServer) {
              config.externals.push((context, request, callback) => {
                resolve(request, { basedir: dir, preserveSymlinks: true }, (err, res) => {
                  if (err) {
                    return callback()
                  }
                  if (
                    res.match(/node_modules[/\\].*\.css/)
                    && !res.match(/node_modules[/\\]webpack/)
                    && !res.match(/node_modules[/\\]@aws-amplify/)
                  ) {
                    return callback(null, `commonjs ${request}`)
                  }
                  callback()
                })
              })
            }
            return config;
          },
          cssLoaderOptions: {
            url: false
          }
      }) 
    )
  )
)
```

I have been trying many solutions, including the following: 
- I should use target server, but I have also tried with "experimental-serverless-trace" but no effect, same error persists 
- Tried also "webpack-asset-relocator-loader" but it doesn't work as well. When utilized, I get the following error: "gRPC binary module was not installed".

To be honest, at this point I do not have any idea where to go from this point.

Thanks!